# Spring - generic method for getting body from ResponseEntity using HttpEntity

Tags: java, spring, httpentity

In my code I am very often using HttpEntity alongside ResponseEntity in a following way:

```
HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<String>(myObject, headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("someurl", HttpMethod.POST, request, String.class);
```

and then

```
response.getBody()
```

I repeat this code all the time,  I was wondering if it is possible to create a generic method that would allow me to get response.body() when I supply it with object I want to send, an url, and a HttpMethod type.
The response body most of the time will be a string, but can be an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below code, here the response body and request body are made generic:

```
public <T, R> T yourMethodName(R requestBody, 
                               MultiValueMap<String, String> headers, 
                               String url, 
                               HttpMethod type, 
                               Class<T> clazz) {
    HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<String>(requestBody, headers);
   //You have to create restemplate Obj somewhere
    ResponseEntity<T> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, type, request, clazz);
    return response.getBody();
}
```